# Botão com texto caixa alta no Android API < 14

Tags: java, android

Vemos que no lançamento do [Android 5.0 Lolipop](https://www.android.com/intl/pt-BR_br/versions/lollipop-5-0/) veio Material Design que por sim mudou muita coisa no Android e junto com isso, o componente de [Dialogs](https://material.google.com/components/dialogs.html#) que por padrão vem com o botão com texto caixa alta como mostra abaixo na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém tenho uma aplicação com [Android 2.3.3 Gingerbrend](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-2.3-highlights.html), que eu gostaria customizar para ficar próximo ao material. Aí caí nesta questão do texto em caixa alta (UPPERCASE). Vi que existe o `android:textAllCaps` que neste caso só pode ser usado a partir da `API 14`.  Quando eu inseri esta propriedade ao meu botão apareceu a seguinte alerta:

> Attribute "textAllCaps" is only used in API level 14 and higher
>   (current min is 10)

Existe algum método que substitui esta propriedade?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O ideal é fazer como o colega @ramaral sugeriu e usar o AppCompatButton, já que ele faz parte de uma biblioteca oficial, testada, depurada etc. Mas, para quem tem alguma restrição quanto ao uso das bibliotecas *Support*, uma solução simples é criar uma *Custom View* que herda de Button e acrescenta o comportamento que você quer. Um exemplo de como ficaria o código da *Custom View*:

```
package com.minhaempresa.ui.customview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.Button;

public class AllCapsButton extends Button {

    public AllCapsButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public AllCapsButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

    }

    public AllCapsButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
        super.setText(text.toString().toUpperCase(), type);
    }

}
```

Com isso, basta, no XML, em vez de Button, usar `com.minhaempresa.ui.customview.AllCapsButton`. Por exemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.minhaempresa.ui.customview.MainActivity">

    <com.minhaempresa.ui.customview.AllCapsButton
        android:id="@+id/botao"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Texto que era minúsculo"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Resultado:

[image: Captura de tela mostrando um celular rodando Android 2.3.3 exibindo uma aplicação que só tem um botão, no qual está escrito, em letras maiúsculas, "TEXTO QUE ERA MINÚSCULO"]

Testado no Android 2.3.3 e no 5.0

Comment: Blz, foi dessa forma que fiz hoje de manhã! Abraços.

Comment: Eu tinha pensado em fazer o override do `getText()` mas o `setText()` também serve.

Comment: @ramaral Eu tinha feito primeiro usando getText() ai depois alterei.

Comment: @ramaral Vivendo, apanhando e aprendendo! Obrigado aí por compartilhar suas experiências.

Comment: @ramaral Nos testes que eu fiz, não consegui o resultado com o `getText`, daí fui pro `setText` e funcionou. Não parece certo alterar o valor real que está lá só para exibir de forma diferente, mas foi o jeito. :/

Comment: Eu testei e funcionou, tanto em xml como em java. `return super.getText().toString().toUpperCase();`

Comment: Em qual versão? Você tirou as referências ao tema `AppCompat` no AppTheme do styles.xml? Com o tema herdando de `AppCompat`, ele estava deixando em maiúsculo aqui mesmo sem fazer nada.

Comment: Tem razão, a forma como testei não garante pois foi na API23.

Comment: @ramaral Ah, blz. :)

Comment: @PabloAlmeida eu só fiz uma pequena alteração, dentro da view. Criei uma função `setTextAllCaps(String str)`, para não mexer em todos os `setText`... ta funciando beleza.

Comment: @CleidimarViana Não entendi. Onde você chama esse `setTextAllCaps`?

Comment: @PabloAlmeida ali no `public void setText` default onde você chama o `super.setText` , eu acabei não utilizando. Eu criei um novo método chamdao `setTextAllCaps` onde passo a mesma configuração `text.toString().toUpperCase()`. Está funcionando beleza, relaxa! =)

Comment: @CleidimarViana OK. É que eu pensei que talvez você tivesse cometendo o mesmo erro que eu na primeira solução que tentei, que era criar um método parecido com o seu e chamá-lo em todos os construtores em vez de sobrepor o `setText`. Isso funciona para o texto definido via XML, mas se você fizer botao.setText no Java, ele não funciona mais (porque o botão já foi construído e o construtor não é mais chamado).

Answer (score 3):

Use o [AppCompatButton.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatButton.html)

Acrescente

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

ao layout raíz

e declare o botão assim:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:textAllCaps="true"
    android:text="uppercase"/>
```

Comment: Neste caso eu precisaria da biblioteca `android.support.v7` que hoje a gente não usa (ainda). Este app que estou trabalhando foi finalizado em no inicio de 2013, então tudo ainda adaptado para api 10, nada de material, nada de padrão, tudo estilo anos 90, estilo aquelas aquelas fontes do word 2003 sabe?!  (hehe) Teria alguma outra forma ou vou ter que baixar a biblioteca?

Comment: Onde estão os textos dos botões? Se estão na declaração do botão, adicionar o atributo ou mudar o texto à mão para maiúsculas dá o mesmo trabalho. Se estão num "resource" o trabalho de os alterar é até menor.

Comment: é um app de uso interno da empresa, e neste projeto eu cheguei e peguei o bonde andando, e andando faz tempo, no entanto eu até ja sugeri a gente fazer uma melhoria, considerando que hoje a quantidade que usa Android 2.3.3 é minima. Eu até criei um serviço para obter informações do dispositivo na hora da instalação, porém ainda não foi para produção. Com isso a gente terá uma estatística de uso, assim a gente poderá tomar alguma decisão de melhoria.

Comment: Estão no `resource`. Inglês, português e chinês. Até vamos disponibilizar para a Africa, mas vão continuar usando como Inglês lá.

Comment: Eu não conheço outra alternativa, ou instá-la a biblioteca ou altera à mão.

Comment: À mão já está, mas não queria permanecer assim porque as vezes eu uso o a mesma chave da string em outras situações, daí então não é legal. Mas vou ver aqui o uso da biblioteca, caso o pessoal não concorde,  eu crio varias strings com uppercase e sem. Mas obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @CleidimarViana Você pode criar uma CustomView que extende Button, e faz esse trabalho de deixar em caixa alta na hora de exibir.

Comment: @PabloAlmeida Boa ideia até porque é fácil de implementar. Coloque uma resposta.

Comment: @ramaral Vou colocar assim que sobrarem uns minutos aqui.

Comment: @PabloAlmeida sua ideia foi bacana, eu já implementei! Se você quiser inserir aqui a resposta, vou te dar os méritos. Mas se você não tiver muito tempo, eu postarei a resposta pois poderá ajudar alguém que precise.

Comment: @CleidimarViana Beleza. Se eu não tiver tempo até hoje à noite, eu te dou o OK aqui.

Comment: @PabloAlmeida Ok.

Comment: @CleidimarViana Escrevi uma resposta com a estratégia que sugeri. Veja se ficou parecido com a sua solução ou se precisa de alguma melhoria. :)

Comment: @ramaral tem que lembrar que  temos que colocar o suporte à API em dependencies  `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'`

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo você utilizar o `AppCompatDialogFragment` para fazer isso!

Essa classe está disponível dentro do `appcompatv7`, e já irá fazer todo o trabalho de utilizar o tema correto para a sua aplicação.

Para utilizar, basta criar uma classe que herde de `AppCompatDialogFragment`:

```
public class ConfirmDialogFragment extends AppCompatDialogFragment {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setTitle(title)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.alguma_string,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        //Fazer algo
                    }
                }
            )
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.outra_string, 
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        //Fazer algo
                    }
                }
            )
            .create();

        return dialog;
    }
}
```

E, para exibir:

```
ConfirmDialogFragment dialog = new ConfirmDialogFragment();
dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), dialog.getClass().getName());
```

**Refs:**

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDialogFragment.html

Comment: Legal cara, mas eu queria fazer isso sem usar a lib `appcompatv7`. Nosso no comentário d @ramaral deu uma ideia bacana para resolver o problema. Obrigado pela ajuda!